# Exiting from foreign module in Python (Signal Handling)

Tags: python, module, try-catch, exit, signal-handling

I wrote a little script that does something extremely time-consuming in Python and I included a signal handling module that listens for SIGINT, SIGQUIT and SIGINFO, printing the status when either SIGQUIT or SIGINFO are inputted by the user and aborting the program when SIGINT(CTRL-C) is entered. The code is EXTREMELY sloppy, because i hacked it down in a few minutes and stole some foreign code - dont worry, ill clean it up as soon as I(or rather, you, because I'm stuck) found the bug:

```
def setup_signals(progress_bar):
import signal
import sys

def progress(*args):
    print(progress_bar)

def killitwithfire(*args):
    print("[x] User interrupted with CTRL-C. Aborting.")
    sys.exit(0)

for sig in (signal.SIGINFO, signal.SIGQUIT):
    signal.signal(sig, progress)
for sig in (signal.SIGINT,):
    signal.signal(sig, killitwithfire)
print("Sig handlers built:\n Press Ctrl+T(BSD/OS X) or Ctrf+4(Linux) for progress.")
print("Press CTRL-C to abort.")
```

Now, the problem is that when CTRL-C is entered, the message in killitwithfire() - sorry for the bad reference - is printed, but it won't exit.

The code in which this is executed is inside a try/catch/ block. If that is the problem, how can I exit from within this signal handling module? If it is not the problem, then what is it?

Comment: Sorry, the indenting is off completely. The def setup_signals includes all the code below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal handling is not done in the main thread, so calling `sys.exit()` won't do the trick of stopping the main thread.  Actually, calling this will only raise a special internal exception (`SystemExit`) which will terminate the current thread, if uncaught.  There is no python-internal standard way of signaling one thread to please terminate, so ending the signal-handling thread won't terminate the main thread.

You have several options.

One is to check inside the longrunner thread for a certain condition (global variable or `threading.Condition` or similar), and if this states to "please terminate", then stop looping.

Another is to use the operating system's facilities and kill your process with all its threads (e. g. by sending a signal you don't catch, e. g. SIGKILL, to yourself).

Comment: Thank you very much. That was not the answer I was hoping for, but at least I can do a workaround then.